# Can I set ToolBar items in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Feel free to suggest an alternate approach to my problem if this isn't the best way to go about it.

I have a ToolBarTray and a TreeView. The tree has 2 items that are Concrete1 and Concrete2 classes respectively. I want the toolbar to have a different menu depending on which type of item is selected in the tree.

```
<ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ToolBar>
        <ToolBar.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource convert}}" Value="{x:Type root:Concrete1}">
                        <!--what do i do here??-->
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource convert}}" Value="{x:Type root:Concrete2}">
                        <!--what do i do here??-->
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToolBar.Style>

        <ToolBar.Resources>
            <Menu x:Key="awd">
                <MenuItem Header="AWD"></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Menu x:Key="dwa">
                <MenuItem Header="DWA"></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ToolBar.Resources>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>

<TreeView x:Name="tree"  ItemsSource="{Binding Families}"></TreeView>
```

I've gotten as far as being able to set any regular property (background, etc) of the toolbar depending on which item is selected. I don't know how to proceed to add specific Menus to the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. I've only done this with a ContextMenu and outside of a style trigger but I imagine it would be the same principle.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="myMenuItem"></StaticResourceExtension>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```